# editing components added by netbeans in java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am building gui in netbeans... Or trying to is more like it. I keep getting an error in my code in the gray area that netbeans adds which evidently is a area that I can not edit.

it currently says this...

```
 answerBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Answer Call" }));
        answerBox.addPopupMenuListener(new javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener() {
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
            }
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
                answerBoxPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(evt);
            }
            public void popupMenuCanceled(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
            }
        });
```

the error is on this line

```
 answerBoxPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(evt);
```

In order to fix it when it says I need to remove answerBox from the beginning of the line, and  I don't recall even adding a `popupmenu` in the first place so I am trying to figure out how to

1. hot to edit this line of code to see if it fixes my problem?
2. how can I delete things like this from the designer mode if they are giving me problems?

Comment: It appears that the event method `answerBoxPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible` may no longer exist.  You could go into the "Events" tab of the property sheet and remove the associated event. Failing that, you could open the file in something like `NotePad++` and simply remove the entire listener registration code block

Comment: lol thank you.. I feel so dumb that was so simple... please make answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Yes, it takes a computer to makes feel truly dumb...mine are masters of it...

Comment: lol true! haha answer so I can accept

Comment: Waiting for SO to let me :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the event method `answerBoxPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible` may no longer exist.

You could go into the "Events" tab of the property sheet and remove the associated event.

Failing that, you could open the file in something like NotePad++ and simply remove the entire listener registration code block